# Reset character encoding on a page layout in Visual Studio. Reset back to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, special-characters

How do I reset a page layout character encoding back to UTF-8 in visual studio?

I'm having a solution in visual studio with all my page layouts, masterpages etc. When developing I've been mocking some page layout changes in SharePoint designer. When copy the source code from SharePoint Designer into Visual studio the file changes encoding!!

Is there a simple way to force or turn the encoding back to UTF-8 so I can get special Norwegian characters working..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible by using the `File -> Advanced Save Options..` menu in Visual Studio when you have opened the file with incorrect encoding.

I think `Western Europe (1252)` should work as well in your scenario, besides `UTF-8`